# Express.js: Can't redirect after using session middleware

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am writing an authentication middleware and it is supposed to redirect to previously visited page after successful login our logout. Here's the complete config block:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: '__YouDontKnow__', store: new RedisStore }));
  app.use(authCheck.run);
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Now when `app.use(authCheck.run)` is under `app.use(express.session)`, Express throws error: *Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.*

If I move this call above `app.use(express.session)`, it throws a 500 error saying that *session* is undefined. And my auth function depends on the session object.

What can I do?

**EDIT:** here's the authCheck function:

```
exports.run = function (req, res, next) {
  var urlparser = GLOBAL.urlparser,
      url = req.urlp = urlparser.parse(req.url, true),

      goToLastPage = function() {
        var redirectUrl = (req.session.lastVisitedPage) ? req.session.lastVisitedPage : '/';
        console.log("goToLastPage(%s)", redirectUrl);
        res.redirect(redirectUrl);
        return;
      }

  // Log out
  if (url.pathname == '/user/logout') {
    req.session.destroy();
    console.log('User has logged out');
    goToLastPage();
  }

  // Log in
  if (url.pathname == '/user/login' && req.method == 'POST') {
    var email = req.body.login.email,
        password = req.body.login.password;

    req.session.auth = true;
    req.session.userId = 1;

    console.log('User has logged in');

    goToLastPage();
  }

  next();
  return;
}
```

Comment: can you give some more information on authCheck.run

Comment: Does anything route at all? Is there anything you do in particular that throws the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a `return` after you call `goToLastPage()`.  You're still calling `next()` after you have called `res.redirect` which calls the next piece of middleware in the chain, likely eventually ending up hitting one of your routes, which then tries to set a header and fails.